# Which type of bean causes the least amount of flatulence without soaking?

Tags: beans

If you wanted to cook unsoaked beans, which type of bean would have the least chance of producing flatulence?

For instance,I put some pinto beans in an instant pot for 30 minutes after eating a 1/2 cup worth I feel this would not be a good choice for a bean that produces minimal flatulence with soaking over night.

On the other hand, I cooked some unsoaked lentils in a canner and didn’t have any Problems with that.

Comment: I think this question might be off-topic on this site and would fit [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) better.

Comment: Why would asking about beans on a vegetarian web site be off topic?

Comment: For the same reason why asking about carrots would be. There is an [existing discussion on meta for this](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-affect-vegetarians-and-non-vegetarians-alike). Seems like currently we evaluate this on a case-to-case basis which is why I said might be off-topic. Main point being, there isn't anything in the question that would make it fit here better than on a general cooking Q&A.

Comment: I don't think this question is off topic - in particular it's similar to [this well-received question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/which-foods-benefit-from-soaking-before-cooking). I suspect you will only get anecdotal responses though. My only comment is that lentils cooked in excess water until completely mushy probably don't retain resistant starch, as you noticed. (Also, it's against network-wide policy to close a question on one site because it is on-topic on another)

Answer (score 2):

[Perceptions of flatulence from bean consumption among adults in 3 feeding studies](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22104320/) states

> It is important to recognize there is individual variation in response to different bean types.

A review in MedMD on beans states [All Beans Aren't the Same in Gassy Side Effects](https://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/news/20111123/all-beans-arent-the-same-in-gassy-side-effects#1)

So any answer to your question is likely to be subjective. Also, when comparing beans to lentils it is probably worth to consider that lentils are often cooked un-soaked, but beans are frequently pre-soaked and/or require (much) longer cooking times than lentils. So flatulence comparison will be influenced by cook time as well as food type. From personal experience, cooking any beans with kelp might assist digestion.

Answer (score 0):

Lentils cause less flatulence and they don't need soaking. Try the small ones first (red lentils, beluga lentils...)

Answer (score 0):

#### The short answer is

- [Phaseolus coccineus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaseolus_coccineus)
- [Flat bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_bean)
- [Pea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pea)
- [Snow pea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_pea)
- [Black-eyed pea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-eyed_pea)
- [Phaseolus vulgaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaseolus_vulgaris)
- [Vicia faba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicia_faba)
- [Lathyrus clymenum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lathyrus_clymenum)
- [Lentil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lentil)

#### Flatulence depends on many factors

1. on the **bean-side**, like:

   - presence of **toxins** (try ecologically grown types)
   - presence of **salt** in the prepared food (try to lower)
   - soaking time and the **acid-base balance** of soaking liquid (can be improved with [Sodium bicarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate))
2. from the **consumer** side:

   - eat beans **regularly** to get used to your organization
   - **chew thoroughly** to increase the digestive surface to have less strain on stomachs.
   - varies by [Dosha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosha) and [blood type](https://dadamo.com/txt/index.pl?1001)